# Injecting an EJB into an Automatic Timer EJB returns null

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb

I'm trying to develop e very simple app based on a running thread creating entities in a DB every second in JavaEE on a Glassfish4 Server.

I'm using an Automatic Timer, where I inject an EJB managing the persistence.

The Timer Service is the following one:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class UpdateEJB {

    @EJB
    MeasureEJB measureEjb;

    @Schedule(second = "*/1", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void doWork() {

       measureEjb.create(new Measure());
    }
}
```

While the EJB is:

```
@Stateless
public class MeasureEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "smarthomePU")
    private EntityManager em;

   public Measure create (Measure _measure) {
        em.persist(_measure);
        return _measure;
   }

}
```

The Entity

```
@Entity
public class Measure implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String time;

    private int[] temp;

    private boolean[] water;

    public int[] getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(int[] temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public boolean[] getWater() {
        return water;
    }

    public void setWater(boolean[] water) {
        this.water = water;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Measure() {
        super();
    }

    public Measure(int[] _temp, boolean[] _water) {
        temp = _temp;
        water = _water;
        time = "";
    }

}
```

But when I try to use the MeasureEJB in the UpdateEJB the app stops with a NPE on the create method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the code fragments above, I cannot  see how EntityManager is injected and since your're talking about an NPE the problem may lie there.

Also avoid @Singleton(s) if you don't keep state in your beans. By default your *public void doWork()* is associated with a Write Lock automatically.

Comment: The problem is not with the EntityManager, as when I debug the code i see that the variable measureEjb is null. In any case I'll add the code of the Entity asap

Comment: @sthor69 you may need to check the logs after your application initialization. These may reveal why MeasureEJB  was not initialized.